# SQL/PHP echo count returns 0 even with content

Tags: php, sql

somehow my output on my count is 0 even when i have 4 rows that meet the criteria in my SQL count. For ease I have set the $usrcustomerid to 110 to check for the number. There are only conditions for the my count: if it is pending and matching the usrcustomerid.

my "order" table

[image: 1]

**orders.php**

```
<?php
 session_start();
 require_once('orders-claimed.vc.php');
 echo $lstCountPending['count_pending'];
?>
```

**orders-claimed.vc.php**

```
<?php

  $routePath = "../";

  require_once($routePath . "_config/db.php");
    $dbConfig = new config_db();
    $db = $dbConfig->init();

  require_once($routePath . "_mc/Order.mc.php");
  $mcOrder = new Order_MC();

  $usrcustomerid = 110;
  $lstCountPending = $mcOrder->SelectCountPending($db, $usrcustomerid);
  $lstCountPending['count_pending'] = count($lstCountPending);
```

**Order.mc.php**

```
  public function SelectCountPending($db, $usrcustomerid) {
   $stmt = $db->prepare(
     " SELECT usrcustomerid AS count_pending, status
       FROM order
       WHERE status = 'PENDING'
       AND usrcustomerid = $usrcustomerid "
   );
   $stmt->execute();
   $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return $rows;
  }
```

Comment: are you counting or displaying rows?

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($lstCountPending)` before your assignment `$lstCountPending['count_pending']  = count($lstCountPending);`?

Comment: aside from the counting issue, why not use a `AND usrcustomerid = ?` placeholder and use `->$stmt->execute([$usrcustomerid]);` you're already using prepared statement api, use it correctly, don't inject variables directly to your statements

Comment: You are selecting the `usrcustomerid` and "renaming it `count_pending`. I assume you actually want to `COUNT(*) AS count_pending` and add a `GROUP BY usrcustomerid` clause to your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try
 {$variable} in string

```
public function SelectCountPending($db, $usrcustomerid) {
   $stmt = $db->prepare(
      " SELECT usrcustomerid AS count_pending, status
       FROM order
       WHERE status = 'PENDING'
        AND usrcustomerid = {$usrcustomerid} "
   );
   $stmt->execute();
   $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return $rows;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want the number of rows  you should use COUNT(*)

anyway you are at risk for sqlinjection  ..  for avoid this you should take a look at prepared  statement and binding param 
  in your case assuming your `usrcustomerid` is an integer you could use

```
 public function SelectCountPending($db, $usrcustomerid) {
   $stmt = $db->prepare(
     " SELECT count(*) AS count_pending, status
       FROM order
       WHERE status = 'PENDING'
       AND usrcustomerid = $usrcustomerid "
   );
   $stmt->bindParam(1, $usrcustomerid , PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->execute();
   $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return $rows;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extract the `status` column because you already filter for it always as `'PENDING'`:

```
public function SelectCountPending($db, $usrcustomerid) {
   $stmt = $db->prepare(
     " SELECT usrcustomerid AS count_pending
       FROM order
       WHERE status = 'PENDING'
       AND usrcustomerid = $usrcustomerid "
   );
   $stmt->execute();
   $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return $rows;
  }
```

**You can get all the rows and count them with PHP**:

```
public function SelectAllPending($db, $usrcustomerid='' /*optional parameter*/) {
      $condition = $usrcustomerid ? " AND usrcustomerid = $usrcustomerid " : '';

      $stmt = $db->prepare(
        " SELECT *
          FROM order
          WHERE status = 'PENDING'
          $condition"
      );
      $stmt->execute();
      $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

      return $rows;
  }

$pendings = SelectAllPending();
$numPendings = count($pendings);
```